# In Git, how do I configure my local branches to have a prefix when I push them to a remote?

Tags: git

I work on a team that has a branch naming standard that requires a specific prefix for branches in the central git repository. That prefix is as follows:

```
dev/<name>/<topic>
```

Example:

```
dev/john/my-feature
```

Locally, for sanity reasons, I don't want to have to deal with the prefix. It's boilerplate that makes typing commands more tedious. Instead, I want my branch locally to just be the  `<topic>`, which in the above example is just `my-feature`.

I want to see what kind of push & fetch workflow I can build to make this prefixing as transparent as possible. First, let me share some interesting configuration options I currently have set in my global `.gitconfig`:

```
[push]
    default = current
[remote]
    pushDefault = fork
```

The remote-specific settings may not matter here, but I have included it for completeness. There are three distinct use cases I want to support:

1. When I fetch remote branches that contain the `dev/john` prefix, I want them to appear locally under `refs/remotes/origin/<topic>`. For example, remote branch `refs/heads/dev/john/my-feature` should get fetched locally to `refs/remotes/origin/my-feature`.
2. When I push the local branch `refs/heads/my-feature` to remote `origin`, it should map to `refs/heads/dev/john/my-feature` on the remote.
3. When I push `refs/heads/master`, it should still go to `refs/heads/master` on the remote. The `master` branch should completely ignore the prefixing.

Here is the remote configuration for `origin` in my repo's `.git/config` that I have so far. Note that I've only been testing `git push` for now, I realize that the fetch refspec doesn't support the first use case above.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@mydomain:myrepo
    fetch = +refs/heads/dev/john/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
    push = refs/heads/*:refs/heads/dev/john/*
```

Here is what I've observed so far:

1. `git fetch origin` so far works in all cases: Branches under `refs/heads/dev/john/` get mapped to `refs/heads/origin/`. And everything else is the normal direct mapping we're all used to.
2. Doing a `git push -n origin master` yielded expected results.
3. Doing a `git push -n origin my-feature` yielded expected results. Specifically:

   - [new branch]          my-feature -> dev/john/my-feature
4. With a local branch named `my-feature` checked out, the command `git push -n origin` push did not respect `push.default`, and instead pushed all local branches. My expectation is that `push.default` is still used in cases where the `remote.origin.push` setting includes a wildcard in the refspec. Without a source branch specified, I want it to still assume I'm pushing the current branch, but just map it to a different remote ref.

The documentation does not support the behavior I'm asserting for the `git push -n origin` case, from what I read. Specifically the [git-push] docs say (emphasis mine):

> When the command line does not specify what to push with `<refspec>...` arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the default `<refspec>` by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration, **and if it is not found**, honors `push.default` configuration to decide what to push.

So all of this, I suppose, is a long way of ultimately asking: How do I make `git push -n origin` give me the same behavior of `git push -n origin my-feature` with the given configuration (noting that a change in configuration itself is acceptable)?

Comment: Did you manage to do that? I need the same but without a fork.